# div class change color from color name to color #code

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use color code. For example #e06666 instead of red.

```
content.push('<p><div class="color red"></div>Whole Foods Market</p>');
```

How should I do it?

Comment: red is a class name, so you could change the appropriate css to use that color.

Comment: So set the style...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this concrete example you should use:

```
content.push('<p><div class="color" style="color:#e06666"></div>Whole Foods Market</p>');
```

However, it's much better to define CSS style:

```
.custom-color {
    color: #e06666;
}
```

and set a class for the *div* tag:

```
content.push('<p><div class="color custom-color"></div>Whole Foods Market</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
content.push('<p><div style="color = #e06666"></div>Whole Foods Market</p>');
```

Comment: It would be `color: #e06666` as appose to `color = #e06666`. I couldn't edit your answer as my edit was too short.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a class and not a color reference, you have to find your css file which would be defined on your page with a  tag or you may have a   block on your page that includes the .red class.

In either location you should see something like this.

```
.red{
    color:red;
}
```

replace the color:red; line with color:#e06666;

Answer (score 0):

You can get `rgb()` value of `"red"` keyword using `window.getComputedStyle()`, convert `rgb()` to hexadecimal see [RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb).

```js
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/5624139/
function componentToHex(c) {
    var hex = c.toString(16);
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}

var content = [];

var div = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.style.color = "red";

content.push(`<p><div class="color ${rgbToHex.apply(null, window.getComputedStyle(div).color.match(/\d+/g).map(Number))}"></div>Whole Foods Market</p>`);

console.log(content);
```